# Calenderview day disable in android

Tags: android, calendar, customization

I am using calenderview in my activity. I want to disable all monday/tuesday (any specific day). But I am not getting any possible option for it. Till now I am able to disable only the days before current date by setting min date.

```
 final Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendarView.setMinDate(newCalendar.getTime().getTime());
```

Is there any way which will allow me to disable all monday?

Comment: You can use other library instead of `CalendarView`?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS can you please suggest me any library which will allow me to do this.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473975/enable-and-disable-the-dates-in-android/21474665#21474665)